# Merge two python pandas data frames of different length + sum common values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have the following problem: I have two pandas data frames of different length containing some rows that have common values and some that are different like this:

df1

```
     s1  s2  s3  s4
sp1   1   0   1   1
sp2   1   1   0   1
sp3   1   1   1   0
sp4   1   1   1   1
```

df2

```
     s1  s2  s3  s4
sp1   1   0   1   1
sp3   1   1   1   0
sp5   1   1   1   1
```

I would like to merge the two tables with the following result:

```
     s1  s2  s3  s4
sp1   2   0   2   2
sp2   1   1   0   1
sp3   2   2   2   0
sp4   1   1   1   1
sp5   1   1   1   1
```

Is that possible to merge the two dataframe and make the addition of the common cells?

Comment: You could do `(df1 + df2).fillna(df1).fillna(df2)`

Answer (score 4):

## Solution

```
df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)
```

or

```
df1.add(df2, fill_value=0).astype(int)
```

This does exactly what you want using arguments intended to solve this exact problem.  I added `astype(int)` at the end to preserve `int`