# how to join and sum columns (of different lengths) in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

lets say I have the following dataframes

df1

```
name  value 
a      3   
b      4
c      5
```

df2

```
name  value 
b      2  
a      1
```

and I want to make a dataframe like this (there can be many value columns)

```
name  value 
a      4   
b      6
c      5
```

Does anyone know how I would do this?

Comment: For completeness, it's helpful including what you've tried.

Comment: Perhaps, the following might assist [Sum columns of two pandas dataframes of different sizes only for certain rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52868169/sum-columns-of-two-pandas-dataframes-of-different-sizes-only-for-certain-rows), and [Merge two python pandas data frames of different length + sum common values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37166111/merge-two-python-pandas-data-frames-of-different-length-sum-common-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can temporarily set "name" as index:

```
df1.set_index('name').add(df2.set_index('name'), fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  name  value
0    a    4.0
1    b    6.0
2    c    5.0
```

Comment: Any reason why you unaccepted the answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
df2.set_index("name").reindex(df1.name).fillna(0).astype(int)+df1.set_index("name")
```

out：

```
      value
name       
a         4
b         6
c         5
```

Comment: Hi G.G, thank you for your answer! The community would appreciate if you would extend your answer with the description explaining how the proposed solution works.